# Java. Работа с потоками в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, потоки-данных

День добрый. 
В данный момент занимаюсь тем, что "прохожу" книгу "JAVA 8 для Чайников" Барри Берда.

Использую Eclipse v1. build 20130919-0819 JRE 8u131

Затык случился на потоках. 
В коде есть такие строки:

```
ArrayList<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>(); 
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 

    fillTheList(sales); 

    System.out.println(currency.format(
            sales.stream()
                .filter((sale) -> sale.item.equals("DVD"))
                .map((sale) -> sale.price)
                .reduce(0.0 (price1, price2) -> price1 + price2)));
}
```

Eclipse предлагает мне создать локальную переменную sale (так как sale cannot be resolved to a variable), но насколько я понял из учебника, такого быть не должно, да и вариант там финальный, и должен работать.

Очень надеюсь на вашу подсказку.

Comment: С `sale` проблем нет в обеих строках. А вот `reduce` точно написан неправильно: после `0.0` должна быть запятая.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо, запятую и правда пропустил

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался прост. Нужно было [обновление](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) для *Eclipse*.

Ну и далее меняем значение в программе
`windows > preferences > java > compiler > compiler compliance level > 1.8`